# ¿"Wishful thinking" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, solicitud-de-modismo

John Carlin es un periodista y escritor británico. Su madre es española y, supongo que por ello, escribe en castellano con frecuencia. Hoy lo leo en El País en su artículo [*La voluntad del pueblo*](http://elpais.com/elpais/2017/06/25/opinion/1498420558_903138.html):

> Al hacer esta afirmación estoy atento a la posibilidad de haber sucumbido a lo que en inglés llaman el “**wishful thinking**”, frase hecha que retrata uno de los errores más frecuentes en los que caen los gobernantes, los políticos y la gente en general: convencerse de que el mundo es como uno quiere que sea y que las cosas saldrán como uno desea que salgan.

Como veis, destaco la expresión *wishful thinking* con la que etiqueta aquello que uno quiere creer, dejando de lado la objetividad y centrándose en querer que sea de una forma. Cada vez la oigo más en conversaciones en castellano. Por ejemplo:

> Seguro que encontraré aparcamiento delante de casa. Bueno... llámalo *wishful thinking*, pero yo creo que sí que lo lograré.

Sí, decirlo en inglés está bien, pero me pregunto si tenemos alguna expresión equivalente, que mantenga la parte jocosa de "sí, tú sigue con tus ilusiones".

Así a bote pronto se me ocurre la coletilla *llámame iluso*, que se popularizó hace unos años en España por la canción de La Cabra Mecánica *No me llames iluso*.

Comment: He visto la frasecita traducida cuasi-literalmente como *pensamiento deseoso*, lo cual hace que quiera arrancarme los ojos... Se me ocurre que tendría que ser un paralelo de *voluntarismo*, donde en vez de la voluntad (activa) interviniesen los deseos (pasivos), pero hasta ahí llego.

Comment: @walen that does seem to me (+1) to convey the sense of the English phrase and I would suggest you might turn it into an answer.

Comment: LLámalo positivismo llevado adl extremo, pero yo creo que sí que lo lograré.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La traducción habitual de *wishful thinking* es "**expresión de deseo**", es decir, algo así como poner en palabras lo que sólo pertenece al mundo irreal del deseo.

Por eso, la oración donde aparece por lo general la frase en cuestión:

- It's just wishful thinking.

es perfectamente equiparable a la oración, también con un adverbio restrictivo:

- Es sólo una expresión de deseo.

Justamente el adverbio restrictivo viene a recalcar el abismo que a veces existe entre lo que uno desea y la realidad.

Completo mi respuesta con algunos ejemplos de Internet:

[Ejemplo 1](http://cartaabierta.cl/definiciones-de-bachelet-acentuan-diferencias-en-nueva-mayoria/) *“Yo creo que decir que había un giro al centro del gobierno, era lo más parecido a un **wishful thinking**”, añadió, asegurando que la necesidad de moderación que expresan algunos sectores -derecha, empresarios y parte  del oficialismo- eran más bien una **expresión de deseo**.*

[Ejemplo 2](http://www.filosofitis.com.ar/2003/11/15/el-caos-y-la-complejidad-se-vistieron-de-congreso/) *Porque la supuesta tesis de Guillot de que el año que viene será la era de Internet móvil en la Argentina de la mano del GSM fue antes que nada una **expresión de deseo, wishful thinking**, que lo que se puede esperar de un análisis cultural de los cambios en las pautas de uso de los consumidores de tecnología celular en la Argentina.*

[Ejemplo 3](http://connuestraamerica.blogspot.com.ar/2013/01/) De nuevo, una de las principales dificultades opositoras en Venezuela estriba en creerse sus propios ejercicios de **wishful thinking (expresión de deseo).**

(No sigo para no aburrir, pero hay muchos ejemplos más.)

Comment: Hay algo que no suena.  "Wishful thinking" lleva la idea de ilusion.  "Expresion de deseo" puede ser nada más que eso, sin la idea de ilusión".

Comment: @WalterMitty Entiendo que lo que puede no sonarte es que "wishful thinking" se refiere a una forma de pensar y "expresión de deseo" a una forma de decir. La frase en español hace en efecto alusión a un acto posterior, que es expresar lo que se piensa o desea, como cuando uno dice: "Sólo estoy pensando en voz alta." No obstante, puedo garantizarte que es una traducción muy común. Como referencia, agrego algunos enlaces a mi respuesta arriba, que encontré buscando "wishful thinking" "expresión de deseo".

Comment: De acuerdo con @WalterMitty. Expresión de deseo no significa lo mismo. Puede ser la traducción habitual pero eso no la hace buena, ni correcta.

Comment: @MichaelWolf No hay dos traducciones iguales, y eso no hace buena una y mala la otra. Estoy de acuerdo en que "expresión de deseo" puede no siempre ser la mejor traducción para "wishful thinking", pero es perfectamente válida en el contexto en que la di y como "translation equivalent" del "wishful thinking" que expresa la segunda oración del OP: "Seguro que encontraré aparcamiento delante de casa." Si no tienes en cuenta el contexto para una traducción, vas por mal camino. Son muchos los hablantes y traductores que estarían de acuerdo conmigo, por lo que tu desacuerdo no me hace mella.

Answer (score 10):

«**Exceso de optimismo**» es la expresión en español que mejor se adecua al significado e intención de la expresión inglesa, creo.

Fijándonos solo en el significado, podría valer «optimismo» a secas, pero le falta ese puntillo de sarcasmo del original.

La verdad, me sorprendería que en español no existiese alguna expresión más castiza para un concepto así, pero ahora mismo no se me ocurre ninguna. Quizá se podría hacer referencia al **[cuento de la lechera](http://www.mundoprimaria.com/fabulas-para-ninos/cuento-de-la-lechera/)** de alguna forma, al fin y al cabo es un ejemplo de *wishful thinking*.

Comment: Hay un escritor en México poco conocido que define esto como el "pensamiento mágico pendejo", que aunque no es una frase universal se acerca mucho a lo que wishful thinking se refiere

Comment: @fernando.reyes Gran expresión, sin duda, aunque me temo que *pendejo* es una palabra poco usada fuera de México. Pero estoy tentado de usar la expresión incluso aquí en España, a ver qué pasa.

Comment: Ahora sé qué decir a la gente acá que cree en la homeopatia, el reiki, la religión, la utilidad de tocar el claxón y tantas otras cosas. Gracias por compartirla.

Answer (score 5):

Me sorprende que nadie haya sugerido todavía ninguna de las expresiones que tenemos en español relacionadas con "[soñar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YNNUPN4)" en su acepción de

> 2. tr. Discurrir fantásticamente y dar por cierto y seguro lo que no lo es. U. t. c. intr.

e incluso la de

> 4. intr. Anhelar persistentemente algo. *Soñar con grandezas*.

Que transmiten ese significado de "aquello que uno quiere creer, dejando de lado la objetividad y centrándose en querer que [la realidad] sea de una forma [concreta]"

Por ejemplo:

- Ser un soñador
- Soñar despierto
- Estás soñando / Tú sigue soñado...
- Soñar es gratis

Aplicadas al ejemplo de la pregunta

> Seguro que encontraré aparcamiento delante de casa. Bueno... (será que) soy un *soñador*, pero yo creo que sí que lo lograré.
>
> Seguro que encontraré aparcamiento delante de casa. Bueno... déjame *soñar*, yo creo que sí que lo lograré.
>
> Seguro que encontraré aparcamiento delante de casa. Bueno...  *Soñar* es gratis, no?. Quien sabe? Lo mismo hoy sí que lo lograré.

Y si me puedo atrever con una interpretación libre del texto de Carlin...

> Al hacer esta afirmación estoy atento a la posibilidad de haber sucumbido a lo que en español se llama “**soñar despierto | ser un soñador**”, frase hecha que retrata uno de los errores más frecuentes en los que caen los gobernantes, los políticos y la gente en general: convencerse de que el mundo es como uno quiere que sea y que las cosas saldrán como uno desea que salgan.

Answer (score 4):

En adición a otras respuestas, creo que una traducción buena podría ser "**pensamiento positivo**". Tiene la connotación de ser una forma deliberadamente optimista de vivir o de tratar determinados temas. Se trata de algo que tiene seguidores y detractores. No sé si la expresión "wishful thinking" permite esta contraposición, o si es más despectiva. Otro problema puede ser que también tenemos el "positive thinking" en inglés, por lo que seguramente estamos perdiendo algo de significado.

Otra expresión que tampoco es exacta, pero que puede ser buena para traducir determinados contextos, es "**declaración de intenciones**". Creo que se puede definir como una serie de puntos a seguir que alguien se autoimpone para alcanzar una meta. Puede tratarse de cosas demasiado abstractas, o de objetivos máximos cuya total consecución puede ser poco realista; pero que marcan una referencia o línea a seguir.

Comment: _Pensamiento positivo_ tiene su punto, buen apunte. Me parece que pierde un poco de fuelle respecto _wishful thinking_, pues la versión inglesa introduce ese matiz sarcástico que comenta walen en su respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Pensamiento ilusorio.

Lleva el significado de que el pensador no diferencia entre lo deseado y lo real.

La definición en Wikipedia viene al caso: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pensamiento_ilusorio

Comment: ¡Buen descubrimiento! También es verdad que en la [Discusión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discusi%C3%B3n:Pensamiento_ilusorio) de esa página alguien menciona: _"Pensamiento ilusorio" es una traducción muy mala. El significado del término en inglés tiene muy poco que ver con la palabra "ilusorio". Sería mejor renombrar la página con una traducción del término más apropiada como por ejemplo: "pensamiento quimérico" o algo así_.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo.  Creo que "wishful" e "ilusorio" tienen mucho en común. Eso no es decir que "quimérico" no sea mejor.

Comment: Ajá. Qué bien tener a alguien como tú, cuyo idioma nativo es el inglés, para aportar ese granito de arena extra sobre su significado inicial.

Comment: Gracias.  Busqué "grand illusion and wishful thinking" y google me dió una editorial que apareció el pasado setiembre en The New York Times donde dice que una victoria Republicana está basado en "wishful thinking".  El títullo es  "The grand Illusion". También encontre un film en francés llamado La Grande Illusion.

Comment: También pienso en la obra de Carlos Fuentes donde la ilusión y la realidad se confunden.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "wishful thinking" depending to whom is directed will have these translations:

1. General public:

   - es andar/vivir/ soñar en las nubes
   - es ser (mucho lo | muy) iluso/ciego | inocente
   - es vanidad
   - es tener las cosas al frente y no querer verlas
   - jugar con fuego y esperar el no quemarse
2. Formally:

   - es algo ilusorio
   - una utopía
   - un sueño efímero
   - ser Ícaro en vuelo

Comment: Hola Dario y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Qué bueno que dedicaras un tiempo a este sitio. Te animo a registrarte y pasear por el [tour] para seguir aportando contenido de calidad. ¡Hasta pronto!

Answer (score -3):

- Solo buenos deseos
- Solo buenas intenciones