# Why does "(Hacerse la/una) paja" refer to masturbation?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones, vulgaridades

Recently I used the slang term "paja mental" with someone who was not familiar with it, and I had to explain that, among other meanings, the slang expression refers to a sort of "[wishful thinking](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21324/5481)" where the idea is so fantastic, impossible, erratic, nonsense, etc. that it's like an exercise of "mental onanism". Quoting [this site (AsíHablamos.com)](https://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Paja%20mental.php) it would be an "erratic, complicated, absurd and too complex reasoning only to be understood by the one doing it".

I also had to explain that "[paja](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RTGhL0f)" and the expression "hacerse una/la paja" are slang for masturbation. They asked me for the origin of this expression and I could not respond. I did a quick search online and could only find one entry in Meneame which didn't seem very trustworthy (also, I'm at work and I need to avoid NSFW sites, which unfortunately might be among the results of your query, given the keywords involved).

How did the term "paja" and the expression "hacerse una/la paja" come to refer to masturbation?

Comment: Con certeza no te podría decir pero me es fácil imaginar.

Comment: Relacionada: [Why does “Hacerse una chaqueta” refer to masturbation?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30572/5481)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según el [blog de Alfred López](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/por-que-el-acto-de-masturbarse-se-conoce-como-hacerse-una-paja/):

> [...] la mayoría de expertos apuntan que se denomina **‘paja’** a la **masturbación** (en un principio masculina y después generalizadamente) debido a que el movimiento de bajar y subir la piel del pene recordaba el gesto que se hacía en el entorno agrícola a la hora de separar la semilla del cereal del tallo en el que crece (lo que comúnmente conocemos paja).

Comenta además otra posible etimología, defendida al parecer por algunos lingüistas:

> [...] hay quien defiende que es consecuencia de una curiosa transformación desde el verbo latino **‘pascere’**, cuyo significado era *‘satisfacer’*, *‘dar gusto’* y que en una de esas carambolas de la lengua acabó evolucionando en el árabe *‘paššaša’* (acariciar) de ahí a ser acortada en *‘pašša’* que dio como resultado la mencionada ‘paja’.

El caso más antiguo que encuentro en el CORDE es de 1962, en una obra de Mario Vargas Llosa, aunque dado que es una expresión vulgar esto no es indicativo de su antigüedad, se podría haber transmitido oralmente desde bastante tiempo atrás. En todo caso la primera explicación me parece la más plausible por su sencillez.

Comment: Pues es lo que imaginaba jajaja

Comment: @walen Jajaja. Esa anécdota de Arguiñano la había oído yo también. Si es que no es tan evidente ;-)