# Why does “Hacerse una chaqueta” refer to masturbation?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, méxico, vulgaridades

Yesterday I published the question [Why does “(Hacerse la/una) paja” refer to masturbation?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30548/5481) which got a comment saying that in Mexico they use instead the expression

> Hacerse una chaqueta

In the DRAE that is the second meaning for [*chaqueta*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8bi8TF7)

> 2. f. vulg. Méx. masturbación.

The aforementioned contribution didn't explain the origin of this expression, so I thougth I would take the liberty to ask for it, since it is related to the first question and can be interesting to know the origin of this expression (and maybe a little bit more challenging to find out).

Why does “Hacerse una chaqueta” refer to masturbation?

Comment: Es difícil buscar referencias, dado lo común de la palabra, pero por imaginar, entiendo que puede ser por la forma en la que la mano rodea y envuelve al miembro, al igual que una chaqueta envuelve al cuerpo. Claro que entonces también se podría haber llamado _chaleco_, o _jersey_, o _abrigo_, o...

Comment: @Charlie, sí, supongo que al igual que con al otra pregunta (enlazada) será superobvio una vez lo confirmemos, pero quería añadir la pregunta al repertorio del stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En [esta página](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?chaqueta) encontré una posible explicación:

> Una teoría es que provino de "chaira" (de origen gallego), que es una
>   cuchilla curva que utilizan los zapateros para cortar la suela de los
>   zapatos que reparan, pues el corte involucra poner la mano en posición
>   similar (incluso existe la expresión "hacerse una chaira"). Igualmente
>   chaira es aquel artefacto que utilizan los carniceros para afilar los
>   cuchillos; el movimiento se parece mucho al de la masturbación.
>   Probablemente en el pasado se utilizó chaira y con el tiempo empezó a
>   utilizarse chaqueta como eufimismo hasta que se volvió vulgar.

Comment: Thank you! No other theories? No link with "jack off" for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Yo pensaba que era por el movimiento de subir y bajar la cremallera XD